# echo command not giving correct output

Tags: command-line, scripts

I try to create output like `12DEC2013bhav.csv.zip` in the script below.

But it is giving me something like `12DEC.csv.zip` instead:

```
for (( i = 2013; i <= 2014; i++ ))
do
    for m in JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC
    do
        for (( d = 1; d <= 31; d++))
        do
            echo "$d$m$ibhav.csv.zip"
        done
    done
done
```

How do I correct it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to reference a variable called `$ibhav` (not `$i`).

Variables can be more than one character, and in your example, the shell has no way to tell if you meant `$i` or `$ibhav` (or `$ibha` or `$ibh` or `$ib`).

The fix is to bracket your variable names:

```
echo "${d}${m}${i}bhav.csv.zip"
```

so that it's unambigious which variable you're referencing.

From [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bash.1.html):

```
   Parameter Expansion
        The `$' character introduces parameter expansion, command substitution, or
        arithmetic expansion.  The parameter name or symbol to be expanded may  be
        enclosed  in  braces, which are optional but serve to protect the variable
        to be expanded from characters immediately following  it  which  could  be
        interpreted as part of the name.

        When  braces  are  used,  the  matching  ending brace is the first `}' not
        escaped by a backslash or within a quoted string, and not within an embed‐
        ded arithmetic expansion, command substitution, or parameter expansion.

        ${parameter}
               The  value  of  parameter  is substituted.  The braces are required
               when parameter is a positional parameter with more than one  digit,
               or  when  parameter  is  followed by a character which is not to be
               interpreted as part of its name.  The parameter is a shell  parame‐
               ter as described above PARAMETERS) or an array reference (Arrays).
```

Comment: Looks somewhat changed, but I only cited the relevant section of 'man bash'. It's hard to find for beginers. (And for anybode else too, for that matter.)

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/guides.html - `Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide` -- recommended reading for Bash Scripting.

Comment: Note `echo "$d$m${i}bhav.csv.zip"` works too--there's no ambiguity in the first two, as a variable name cannot contain a `$`. (Arguably `echo "${d}${m}${i}bhav.csv.zip"` is prettier due to symmetry, though.)